# bada Programming - Tutorials/Guides

Tags: c++, bada

I'm new to bada and I want to develop an application on bada 2.0. Are there any good tutorials out there? I have tried searching online but found no results. I realized that the bada IDE for 2.0 has some differences compared to the old IDEs.

Maybe to start of with, what is or what does this do?:

> In src folder: AppName.cpp, AppNameEntry.cpp, AppNameForm.cpp
>
> In inc folder: AppName.h, AppNameForm.h

Also, what are the differences when creating bada C++/Flash application project, bada web application project, bada UI sequencer project, bada test, and project? Can some one help and guide me out?

Comment: Have you tried the tutorial that comes with the SDK itself? Since bada is not a very popular platform I really doubt you can get any "external" tutorials that will be better than the one provided with SDK.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. I've seen the examples that are provided with SDK. They are quite helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing a tutorial series, here's the link: http://drstrangecode.org/series/bada-from-scratch/

Hope you like it!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for responding! I have read up on your site too! I have a question on listview though.

Answer (score 0):

This is bada developer documentation link: [http://developer.bada.com/help_2.0/index.jsp](http://developer.bada.com/help_2.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.cppapireference.help/namespaceOsp.html).